# html <button> tag renders strangely in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, button, alignment

I have the following code that basically displays a `<button>`, and inside the button two `<div>`s, one aligned at the top-left corner of the button, the other aligned at the bottom-right corner:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      <!--
      .button {
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: yellow;
      position: relative;
      padding: 0px;
      }

      .child_top_left {
      position: absolute;
      top: 5px;
      left: 5px;
      background-color: blue;
      }

      .child_bottom_right {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 5px;
      right: 5px;
      background-color: red;
      }
    -->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="button">
      <div class="child_top_left">top-left</div>
      <div class="child_bottom_right">bottom-right</div>
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

It all works fine in Internet Explorer or Safari, but in Firefox something is displayed strangely. It looks like Firefox considers that the 'top' of the button is actually located at the middle of the button.

Anyone encountered this behavior? Maybe there is some workaround for it?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see `bottom-right` in IE8, and `top-left` is more at the bottom than at the top

Comment: question really belongs to doctype.com

Comment: I tried in IE7 and they show allright... Maybe IE7 is wrong and IE8 and FF are doing it the right way? But why consider the middle line to be the 'top' ?

Comment: I think the wrapping of divs in a button is totally wrong, and you might need to use ´<input type="button" />` for a button. Check http://www.doctype.com , that's where the webguys answer you're questions.

Comment: Also posted to doctype.com. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Remarkable: button renders fine in quirks mode (which is actually a bad mode), but renders "strangely" in strict mode. In other words, you've omitted the doctype or used a wrong doctype (add `<!doctype html>` to top and you'll see that it behaves same in ALL browsers, including IE --which is good). However, I can't answer why the line height of the button content cannot be shifted to top in strict mode. This is indeed *strange*.

Comment: Strange... It is as if Firefox and IE8 center everything, as they would do with normal text inside the button, and that there is no way to "disable" that... Chrome seems to do that to for static and relative elements, but not for absolutely positioned once. - IE7, it seems, has also stumbled upon the correct rendering, which has since been "fixed" in IE8. *(That's M$ for you xD)* -- I would put this down as a bug in Firefox and IE8. I can at least not see anything in the standard that would explain this.

Comment: The question on doctype: http://doctype.com/html-button-tag-renders-strangely-firefox

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this has been answered on DocType or not, but I managed to find a simple workaround in Firefox; I don't have an instance of IE to test in, but basically, you just wrap your button contents in a div:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      <!--
      .button {
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: yellow;
      position: relative;
      padding: 0px;
      }

      .child_top_left {
      position: absolute;
      top: 5px;
      left: 5px;
      background-color: blue;
      }

      .child_bottom_right {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 5px;
      right: 5px;
      background-color: red;
      }

      .button_container {
          width: 300px;
          height: 200px;
      }
    -->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="button">
      <div class="button_container">
          <div class="child_top_left">top-left</div>
          <div class="child_bottom_right">bottom-right</div>
      </div>
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```